# Node js server is not working with apache proxy in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, reverse-proxy, node.js, apache2

I'm running Node js server in port 8080. Apache is running in port 80 with **https**. I wanted to run Node in apache with **https**. I followed tutorial from [here](https://boriskuzmanovic.wordpress.com/2006/10/20/apaches-proxypass-on-ubuntu/).  Here is my config file.

**Node.conf:**

```
 `<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com

   SSLProxyEngine On
   SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
   SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyVia Full
 <Proxy *>
    Require all granted
 </Proxy>

 <Location /node>
  ProxyPass https://127.0.0.1:8080
  ProxyPassReverse  https://127.0.0.1:8080
</Location>

  <Directory "/var/www/html/node">
     AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Problem:**

Site working If Put: `http://mys-site.com:8080/test?`
What I wanted: `https://my-site.com/test?`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your proxy configuration (Apache) isn't listening on port 443.

You basically have to change two things:

**1 - Ensure Apache is listening on 443.**

Check your Apache configuration file and make sure he is listening in 443.

On Centos would be in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

An entry like:

```
Listen 80
Listen 443
```

**2 - Correct your Apache configuration**

Your `Node.conf` so it need to respond connections inbound to port 443:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com

   SSLProxyEngine On
   SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
   SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyVia Full

 <Proxy *>
    Require all granted
 </Proxy>

 <Location /node>
  ProxyPass https://127.0.0.1:8080
  ProxyPassReverse  https://127.0.0.1:8080
</Location>

  <Directory "/var/www/html/node">
     AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that I'd only changed the listening port on your Vhost config.
You also would want to check your TLS configuration. Maybe your Apache configuration have set it up in a different file like `/etc/httpd/conf.d/00-ssl.conf`. Anyway, you should check https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Recommended_configurations for recommended security configurations regarding TLS.

I hope that help you.

[]'s